# Does sorting a union in postgres take advantage of an index?

Tags: postgresql

Say there are two separate tables, and both have the indexed field `release_date`

```
SELECT * FROM top_rated_films
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM most_popular_films
ORDER BY release_date;
```

Will the order by utilize the indexes in any way?

If not, would:

```
SELECT * FROM top_rated_films ORDER BY release_date
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM most_popular_films
ORDER BY release_date;
```

speed it up by having the first set pre-sorted?

Comment: I wouldn't even be certain whether that's parsed to `(SELECT * FROM top_rated_films) UNION ALL (SELECT * FROM most_popular_films ORDER BY release_date);` or to `(SELECT * FROM top_rated_films) UNION ALL (SELECT * FROM most_popular_films) ORDER BY release_date;` (the latter is what you want)

Comment: Ah, you're good: [`ORDER BY` effectively binds less tightly than `UNION`](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/16814.1280268424@sss.pgh.pa.us)

Comment: "*Will the order by utilize the indexes in any way?*" - use `EXPLAIN` to find out.

Comment: The answer might depend on the version...

Comment: No it won't use the index, but if both `top_rated_films` and `most_popular_films` are a list of films, they are probably based on a single `film` table, so your query can probably be re-written without a `union`

Answer (score 0):

In the case of `UNION ALL`, PostgreSQL can use the indexes (at least in v15, where I tested):

```
EXPLAIN (COSTS OFF)
SELECT * FROM top_rated_films
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM most_popular_films
ORDER BY release_date;

                                     QUERY PLAN              
══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
 Merge Append
   Sort Key: top_rated_films.release_date
   ->  Index Scan using top_rated_films_release_date_idx on top_rated_films
   ->  Index Scan using most_popular_films_release_date_idx on most_popular_films
(4 rows)
```

The `UNION` case cannot use the index, since it needs to sort on all columns to remove duplicates.